# The color depth 1 is not supported

Tags: itext

I am using iTextSharp version 5.5.2.0 and when trying to load the attached pdf sample [058780-02.pdf](http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/The-color-depth-1-is-not-supported-td4661100.html) I get an exception in the ImageRenderInfo.GetImage() method the "PdfImageObject" is not returned and with a message saying "The color depth 1 is not supported". 
Any suggestions? 
Thanks, 
Abedellatif

Comment: The pdf specification defines an own bitmap image format which is extremely flexible, in particular concerning the supported colour spaces. `ImageRenderInfo.GetImage()` attempts to export it in way compatible with normal image formats. Due to the extreme flexibility of the pdf bitmap format, this is not always possible faithfully. Itext does not try to create unfaithful exports. Your pdf seems to be such a case. Thus, you get the exception.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you think there is a workaround to be able to load such PDF using iTEXT?

Comment: You could implement an addition to itext which can cope with your file. IIRC your image is black&white modeled as greyscale with colour depth 1. It should be possible to expand this into a full greyscale or even colour image.

Comment: Your suggestion implies that I have access to the way the images are to be embedded to the source PDF. Actually I do not have this access I am presented with PDFs that I have to load and open with iTEXT. Do you think an extension to the GetImage source code will help? Is it possible?

Comment: *Your suggestion implies that I have access to the way the images are to be embedded to the source PDF.* - No, it doesn't. I was talking about an addition to iText extraction of images, not iText image drawing.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution on this?

Answer (score 2):

i fixed it, modify the iTextSharp source code `PdfImageObject` class `FindColorspace` method  at 222 line add

```
if (PdfName.CALGRAY.Equals(tyca) || PdfName.DEVICEGRAY.Equals(tyca)) {
    stride = (width * bpc + 7) / 8;
    pngColorType = 0;
}
```